# How do I clear the playlist in Videos?

Tags: videos, audience

Basically the title. How can I clear or edit the playlist in Videos/Audience. I can't see any button or anything that clears it. This seems like basic functionality but I can't find it.

Comment: here is my branch for this bug:
https://code.launchpad.net/~artem-anufrij/audience/remove-playlist-item/+merge/274641

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are right. There is no button or command on the gui to delete the played videos.

---

But you can delete the last played videos over the terminal with following command.

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.audience last-played-videos []
```

Comment: This is the related bug report on Launchpad: [Bug #1374248 "can't remove playlist item"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/audience/+bug/1374248)